# Sort 'ls' output by name

Tags: unix, ls

Can you sort an [ls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) listing by name?

Comment: If it's not sorting by name without any arguments, you might want to check if ls has been aliased to something else, or simply invoke it using the full path which would eliminate any aliases that exist.

Comment: gnu-coreutils ls sorts by default. What system are you using (as other have asked)

Comment: Are you sure your asking to sort by name and not by type (ie. directory first then files)??

Comment: Capital letters come before lowercase letters, thus file Z comes before file a... how can I fix that?

Comment: man page says 'sorted separately and in lexicographical order'. Files are sorted according to the first character: numerical [0..9] and UPPER characters [A..Z] and lowe characters [a..z]

Comment: @tvanfosson how do I check that?

Comment: @user770 use the "alias" command (without any arguments) to list any aliases that you've set up, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)

Comment: @tvanfosson this printed no output and confirmed my issue (capital letters take precedence). Thanks :)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

My ls sorts by name by default. What are you seeing?

`man ls` states:

> List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none of `-cftuvSUX` nor `--sort` is specified.

Comment: `ls` doesn't sort if `-c1` specified: is there a way to get it to do so?  (`--sort=name` doesn't seem to work)

Comment: That is not true. with `ls -la`, i see: `.bashrc - can - .config - Downloads - .local - tmp`, sort be name would be: `.bashrc - .config - .local - Downloads - can - tmp`

Comment: mine says 100.jpg comes before 10.jpg. Makes sense I guess if "0" comes before "." but its still not intuitive

Comment: I'm seeing "M" before "b". Confused. Wait, does capitalisation matter?

Comment: @dhc – `ls -c1` sorts by creation time (the last change to an inode, _not_ birth time), newest to oldest, in a single column. `ls -cl` loses that sort order unless you use `ls -clt`. If you don't want to sort by creation time, don't use `-c` without `-l`.

Comment: I'm seeing `_` come before `1` despite the fact that this is not properly ASCII sort order.  I'm also seeing inconsistency based on whether or not there is a file extension (e.g. "A" comes before "A1" but "A.jpg" comes *after* "A1.jpg)!!!

Comment: @Michael it's not based on an ascii sort, it's based on collation in the locale.

Comment: Yes, /bin/ls should default to sorting by name, according to the man page.  I actually noticed a specific (small) bug in /bin/ls on a PopOS machine, but it behaves correctly on an Ubuntu machine.  It's in a test suite for my Fexl project so I'll just link to the comment here:  https://github.com/chkoreff/Fexl/blob/b0854ee62a5dfdce88453d0925dfbfb2bf6c6e94/src/test/b14.fxl#L15

Answer (score 152):

For something simple, you can combine **ls** with **sort**.  For just a list of file names:

```sh
ls -1 | sort
```

To sort them in reverse order:

```sh
ls -1 | sort -r
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort files like this: `ls | sort -n` _1.1.1;
1.1.2;
1.1.3;
2.10.1;
2.10.15;
2.10.2;
2.10.20;
2.10.21;
2.1.1;
2.1.10;
2.1.15;
2.1.2;
2.1.3;
2.1.4;
10.1.1;
10.1.2;
10.1.3;
11.0.1;
11.0.2;
11.0.20;
11.0.21;
11.0.22;_ As you can see **2.10.15 before 2.10.2**.

Comment: I'm doing some android development on a Pidion device, and ls doesn't automatically sort, so this was very helpful! The only problem is that it looks like it sorts soft links but doesn't sort files, for some reason

Comment: On Mac, it looks like that second command can be shortened to `ls -1r`.

Comment: @BBK sort -V will sort by version numbers, so you get .. 2.10.2; 2.10.15; .. from man sort .. --sort=WORD will  sort according to WORD: general-numeric -g, human-numeric -h, month -M, numeric -n, random -R, version -V

Comment: I recently noticed on one machine that "ls -1" was returning names out of order in some cases.  For example:  
  
    $ ls -l tmp
    read_csv.fxl
    read.fxl
    read_ssv.fxl
  
That's clearly out of order because "." < "_", so read.fxl would appear first if sorted.
  
I'm a little surprised that /bin/ls doesn't have an option which simply means "sort by name".  Note that I'm using "ls - 1", as in the numeral ONE, and not "ls -l", which does sort by name.

Answer (score 51):

`ls` from `coreutils` performs a **locale-aware** sort by default, and thus may produce surprising results in some cases (for instance, `%foo` will sort between `bar` and `quux` in `LANG=en_US`). If you want an ASCIIbetical sort, use

```
LC_ALL=C ls
```

Comment: `LANG` ilfnuence the sort behavior, this post help me a lot!

Comment: This worked for me as well. could you elaborate on this? Why does it sort differently?

Comment: This dose work, but output `?` for every non-ascii character when the output is a terminal (bad feature from ls do check if it output to a terminal, work when piping). You can "fix" this with piping to cat, use the `C.UTF-8` locale (if your system supports it) and/or use the `-b` flag. Even better, do not use `ls` at all, better use `

Comment: This helped me to discover that for me, the problem was that some of my filenames contained a hyphen (-), and some an en dash (–). `ls` sorts hyphens before en dashes.

Comment: I had to set `LC_ALL=C` for this to work, as it is suggested in the [ls documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ls).

Changing LANG or LC_COLLATE as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504065/7498073) did'nt work for me (GNU coreutils 8.32).

Answer (score 28):

The beauty of *nix tools is you can combine them:

```
ls -l | sort -k9,9
```

The output of `ls -l` will look like this

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luckydonald luckydonald  532 Feb 21  2017 Makefile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 luckydonald luckydonald 4096 Nov 17 23:47 file.txt
```

So with `9,9` you sort column `9` up to the column `9`, being the file names. You have to provide where to stop, which is the same column in this case. The columns start with `1`.

Also, if you want to ignore upper/lower case, add `--ignore-case` to the sort command.

Comment: What does `-k9,9` mean?

Comment: Found out, it means to sort column `9` up to the same column `9`.  A normal `ls` output looks like this: ```drwx------  8  999 user 4.0K Feb  5  2017 file.txt```, so column 9 being the file names. If you want to ignore the case, use `--ignore-case` on sort.

Answer (score 17):

Files being different only by a numerical string can be sorted on this number at the condition that it is preceded by a separator.

In this case, the following syntax can be used:

```
ls -x1 file | sort -t'<char>' -n -k2
```

Example:

```
ls -1 TRA*log | sort -t'_' -n -k2

TRACE_1.log
TRACE_2.log
TRACE_3.log
TRACE_4.log
TRACE_5.log
TRACE_6.log
TRACE_7.log
TRACE_8.log
TRACE_9.log
TRACE_10.log
```

Answer (score 8):

NOTICE: "a" comes AFTER "Z":

```sh
$ touch A.txt aa.txt Z.txt 

$ ls
```

A.txt   Z.txt   aa.txt

Comment: This is not always true. I don't exactly know the circumstances that make this not true, but on my machine running Ubuntu 12.04 the output of ls is sorted alphabetically (ignoring case).

Comment: Good catch! Seems like it is ordering it based on the ASCII code.. Upper case alphabets are followed by lowercase..

Comment: I noticed that my MacOS sorts first numbers, then uppercase letters, then underscore and then lowercase letters. It's funny that they are not case sensitive. On the other hand, my Debian is case sensitive but it sorts the letters insensitively unless there is a tie, then lowercase wins! Example: ABA.txt  ABb.txt  aBC.txt  AbC.txt  ABc.txt

Comment: I'm on a MAC too. i was disappointed to see the A,Z,a,z type of sorting. I'm here because I prefer to have A,a,Z,a. thanks for your tip. will try out the `normal` solutions here.

Answer (score 4):

From the man page (for bash ls):

> Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuSUX nor --sort.

Comment: There is no "bash ls". Do "which ls"

Comment: @Norbert: You are correct, but `which ls` would succeed even if bash had a builtin ls. Rather, do `builtin ls` in bash, and get an error.

Comment: @Norbert: `which` always returns a path.  Use `type ls` to determine what the shell thinks `ls` is (built-in, function, executable).

Answer (score 3):

The `ls` utility should conform to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 ([`POSIX.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX.1-2001)) which states:

> 22027: it shall sort directory and non-directory operands separately according to the collating sequence in the current locale.
>
> 26027: By default, the format is unspecified, but **the output shall be sorted alphabetically** by symbol name:
>
> - Library or object name, if −A is specified
> - Symbol name
> - Symbol type
> - Value of the symbol
> - The size associated with the symbol, if applicable

Answer (score 3):

ls -X works for that purpose, in case you have aliased ls to a more useful default.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `.bashrc` file for aliases.

Comment: One could just type `alias` to check for all current aliases.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

`ls -lru`

-u with -lt: sort by, and show, access time;

Answer (score 1):

I use ubuntu/debian.

I had files from file1 to file 20. 'ls' would display them out of order and the best method I found for ordering them quickly was `ls -v`

The description in the man pages (man 1 ls) explains

```
-v       natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

I tested this with folders for instance `ls -vd1 */` will display only folders in order. It seems to rely on asci values, so you will see capital letters always take precedence over lower case. This is because capitals are always at a lower asci value.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Debian Jessie, this works nice:

ls -lah --group-directories-first

# l=use a long listing format
# a=do not ignore entries starting with .
# h=human readable
# --group-directories-first=(obvious)
# Note: add -r for reverse alpha

# You might consider using lh by appending to ~/.bashrc as the alias:
~$ echo "alias lh='ls -lah --group-directories-first'" >>~/.bashrc
# -- restart your terminal before using lh command --
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | sort -V
```

will sort nicely if you have numbered files, e.g.

```
File-8.webvtt
File-9.webvtt
File-10.webvtt
File-11.webvtt
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the contents of a directory sorted by **name** using below command:

`ls -h`

Comment: `ls` without any options already sorts by name, `-h` just prints stuff like sizes in "human readable" form.