# Concatenate/Merge css files in order

Tags: bash, css, npm, concatenation

I have a bunch of different css files being generated in `css/` folder with help of libsass. Also I do have `normalize.css` already placed in `css/` folder to allow normalization of css in all browsers. I'm using npm as build tool, and my `package.json` consists something like this:

```
{
.....
"scripts": {
    "test": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "csslint css/*.css",
    "build": "node-sass sass/ -o css/",
    "postbuild": "cat css/*.css | cleancss -o css/main.min.css"
  },
.....
}
```

---

At the build step I'm generating `css` files and in post-build step I'm concatenating all css files into one minified css file.

But during post-build step, the content of `normalize.css` file should come before any other css file content, however the behavior is inconsistent. I need to make sure  that normalize stuff comes ahead of all other css files, any heads up would be helpful.

---

**Tldr**- *Concatenation of bunch of css files results in normalize.css being appended in middle or last. I need it at start of concatenated 
css file.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the [`-I` option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512961/exclude-certain-files-in-ls) of `ls` to exclude `normalize.css` from being listed:

```
cd css/ && cat normalize.css `ls -I normalize.css -I main.min.css` | cleancss -o main.min.css
```

Comment: does `cat` shows files in alphabetical order of their filenames?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal No, `cat` uses the order of its arguments, so here, `normalize.css` first, and then the order from `ls`, which by default is in alphabetical order. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878249/unixs-ls-sort-by-name ). If however you notice it isn't the case, just use `ls -I normalize.css *.css | sort`

Comment: okay... `ls -I normalize.css *.css` even in terminal gives all css files including `normalize.css`, therefore defeating whole purpose. Can you look into it please.

Comment: You're right, it seems to only work when calling ls on a folder. You should only have css files in your `css/` directory, so I believe the edit I just made should work. (By the way, until now, you were reconcatenating `main.min.css` into itself)

Comment: Using `-I normalize.css *css` doesn't make sense, because you're saying "Ignore normalize.css but show me normalize.css" as part of the `*` expansion.  if you want use `-I` you should not use the `*` expansion as well

Comment: @EricRenouf Yes, I've realized that with OP's comment, hence the edit.

Comment: I'm a moron in this stuff. Thankyou again for resolving this quickly :)