# force linux sort to use lexicographic order

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, gnu

I generated a text file with pseudo-random numbers like this:

```
-853340442 1130519212 -2070936922 
-707168664 -2076185735 -2135012102 
166464098 1928545126 5768715 
1060168276 -684694617 395859713 
-680897578 -2095893176 1457930442 
299309402 192205833 1878010157 
-678911642 2062673581 -1801057195 
795693402 -631504846 2117889796 
448959250 547707556 -1115929024 
168558507 7468411 1600190097 
-746131117 1557335455 73377787 
-1144524558 2143073647 -2044347857 
1862106004 -193937480 1596949168 
-1193502513 -920620244 -365340967 
-677065994 500654963 1031304603
```

Now I try to put it in order using linux `sort` command:

```
sort prng >prngsorted
```

The result is not what I expected:

```
1060168276 -684694617 395859713 
-1144524558 2143073647 -2044347857 
-1193502513 -920620244 -365340967 
166464098 1928545126 5768715 
168558507 7468411 1600190097 
1862106004 -193937480 1596949168 
299309402 192205833 1878010157 
448959250 547707556 -1115929024 
-677065994 500654963 1031304603 
-678911642 2062673581 -1801057195 
-680897578 -2095893176 1457930442 
-707168664 -2076185735 -2135012102 
-746131117 1557335455 73377787 
795693402 -631504846 2117889796 
-853340442 1130519212 -2070936922
```

Obviously, `sort` tries to parse strings and extract numbers for sorting. And it seems to ignore minus signs.

Is it possible to force `sort` to be a bit dumber and just compare lines lexicographically? The result should be like this:

```
-1144524558 2143073647 -2044347857 
-1193502513 -920620244 -365340967 
-677065994 500654963 1031304603 
-678911642 2062673581 -1801057195 
-680897578 -2095893176 1457930442 
-707168664 -2076185735 -2135012102 
-746131117 1557335455 73377787 
-853340442 1130519212 -2070936922 
1060168276 -684694617 395859713 
166464098 1928545126 5768715 
168558507 7468411 1600190097 
1862106004 -193937480 1596949168 
299309402 192205833 1878010157 
448959250 547707556 -1115929024 
795693402 -631504846 2117889796
```

Note: I tried `-d` option but it did not help

Note 2: Probably I should use another utility instead of `sort`?

Comment: Looking at the man, you have 6 types of sort: general-numeric -g, human-numeric -h, month -M, numeric -n, random -R, version -V. Try each one and look what is the desirable output.

Comment: This is also found on serverfault: [unix sort treats dash characters as invisible](https://serverfault.com/questions/95579/unix-sort-treats-dash-characters-as-invisible/95593)

Comment: BTW, if you used `sort -n`, *then* you'd get numeric sort. The default behavior is lexicographic but (in your locale) with `-` signs ignored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sort` command takes account of your locale settings.  Many of the locales ignore dashes for collation.

You can get appropriate sorting with

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort filename
```

Comment: man page for sort recommends LC_ALL=C but your variant works also

Comment: @igor.sol, `LC_ALL` sets a bunch of extra things like the language used for error messages. Setting only the collation order is better practice unless one actually intends those side effects.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but LC_ALL=C does (because I have LC_ALL set in my environment and it overrides everything). So if you want just LC_COLLATE, unset LC_ALL.

Answer (score 1):

custom sort with the help of `awk`

```
$ awk '{print ($1<0?"-":"+") "\t" $0}' file | sort -k1,1 -k2 | cut -f2-

-1144524558 2143073647 -2044347857 
-1193502513 -920620244 -365340967 
-677065994 500654963 1031304603 
-678911642 2062673581 -1801057195 
-680897578 -2095893176 1457930442 
-707168664 -2076185735 -2135012102 
-746131117 1557335455 73377787 
-853340442 1130519212 -2070936922 
1060168276 -684694617 395859713 
166464098 1928545126 5768715 
168558507 7468411 1600190097 
1862106004 -193937480 1596949168 
299309402 192205833 1878010157 
448959250 547707556 -1115929024 
795693402 -631504846 2117889796
```

sort by sign only first, then regular sort and remove sign afterwards...

Comment: Have you tested this in a locale where the OP's initial results are reproducible?

Comment: No! obviously didn't.