# Sort output from ls command is not alphabetically

Tags: ls

ls sort alphabetically

char `-` ascii is 45

char `9` ascii is 57

so file `-` sort before `9`

but why file `999-a` sort after `9999a`

```
$ ls -1
-
9
9999a
999-a
```

Comment: use `LC_ALL=C ls -1 9*`,  see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451819/724039

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort 'ls' output by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878249/sort-ls-output-by-name)